# Can nouns such as 雨 be used as a verb?

Tags: grammar

I found sentences such as:

> 1. ここ二、三日はずっと雨です。
> 2. 今週ずっと雨だね。

My question is: Do these sentences omit 雨(が降る)?
Or can nouns such as 雨 be used as a verb in verbal conditions?

Comment: Is your question more about why an adverb like ずっと is modifying a noun like 雨?

Comment: ^ If that's the case: Japanese adverbs can modify nouns too, e.g. **はるか**昔を思い出す。/ **もっと**端に座りなさい。/ **ずっと**先の話だ。/ **すっかり**秋です。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a verb. This kind of sentence such as　「今日は雨です」 can be translated as "It is rainy today." Other examples include 晴 and 曇.